# Detect a url is accessible using HTTP requests

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http-headers, httprequest, httpurlconnection

First are the things I understand:

1) I can send an HTTP HEAD request, and a 200/2XX response code means the content is accessible there.

2) I can send an HTTP GET request with a "Range" header and a 206 response code means the content is accessible.

However, if a given server doesn't support HEAD request and it doesn't comply with the Range header, and more importantly the specific file is a very large file. What is the best way that I can check if the file is accessible? Obviously I don't want to wait for 10 mins for the whole file to be downloaded.

I am using Java with basic `HttpUrlConnection` on Google AppEngine, so some of the particular libraries may not be able to run on this platform.

I am thinking about the best way is to make a GET request and terminate it after the first byte get replied. However, I can't find a way to achieve this via using `HttpUrlConnection`.

Would appreciate anyone give some hints here.

Comment: May be you could try `GET` plus `If-Modified-Since` header with a future date(?). If the content exist and has not been modified, it will respond with 304. This may not work for contents that are generated server side on the fly. But you mention they are specific files, hence, chances are it will have a last modified timestamp at server.

Answer (score 0):

Try `HttpURLConnection.disconnect()` after reading response code etc.

The server, while sending the huge file, would receive an RST from client, and abort its connection too.

Comment: Thanks @zhong.j.yu, I have thought about the same thing, but what happened after calling connection.getResponseCode(), the thread will keep running until all content being retrieved. Unless I'm doing multi-thread here and using another thread to monitor and call the disconnect(), I don't think this is a viable solution.

Comment: it shouldn't. disconnect should be able to free everything.

Comment: Yes, it will free everything but only after getting called. The problem is it will not get called until the content get fully downloaded even if you only call connection.getResponseCode().

Comment: It seems that getResonseCode() only needs the header, not the body of the response. So it should return quickly without downloading the entire content.

Comment: Well, in reality, at least from my test, it is not the case. Once you initialized the connection and made the GET request out, server will start to "push" out the content as long as socket is connected.